# read only field should not be edit from DOM developer tools

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML when we add read only attribute based on condition, it will work fine but I want to restrict that field from developer tools like F12 developer DOM manipulations. User will go developer tools and removing attribute of read only and entering text there, that time entered value is storing in DB due to auto save functionality.

So, How can I restrict user from this type of issue.

Assume that I have no of read only or disabled fields and I want to control all as generic implementation.

**Also , Please let me know, is there any event to fire when developer tools attribute changed.**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Think server side.

Comment: You can't do that. How about not saving the value in your database when it's updated?

Answer (score 3):

You can **not** prevent the HTML code from being edited with the developer console.

If you want to prevent these read only values from being changed and stored in the database, you must perform the appropriate check on the server side.

Answer (score -1):

You can not restrict that field from developer tools.  Better you don't consider read-only values on the screen for saving in database.

Additionally, You can restrict developer tools from getting opened, but intruders will find number of ways to open developer tool.

Comment: What about `Ctrl + shift + I` or just accessing it from the browser menus?